# Ignore certain if when conditions meet

Tags: python

I have a quick question, my sudocode:

```
if a>=b
    raise exception blah blah
else:
    do blah blah
```

But I need to make it that if b=0, then the a>=b code is ignored, and it continues executing the else block of code. even if lets say a=1 and b=0, a>=b is True, since b is 0, the exception will not be raised.

I have tried

```
if a>=b
    raise exception blah blah
elif b=0 or a<b
    do blah blah.
```

with a=1 and b=0.

But this code fails because it evaluates a>b and does not go through the b=0 part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking if `b != 0`:

```
if a >= b and b != 0:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

**Remember** to use `==` or `!=` to check equality. `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: You cannot use `=` in a condition anyway, since assignment in Python is a statement and conditions must be expressions. You will get a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you, I think I just confused my self and couldnt figure out how to do it, I definitely knew this o.O

Answer (score 2):

```
if b and a >= b:
    raise Exception(...)
do(blah)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if b != 0 and a >= b:
    raise exception blah blah
else:
    do blah blah.
```

Comment: In your first case `elif a<b` seems unnecessary. If you fail the first if statement (that `a>=b`) then you can assume `a<b`.

Comment: @Mike That is very true.

Comment: OP doesn't want to raise the exception is `b == 0`